# how to get the content of a web site(single text file) using java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

```
Socket sock = new Socket(HOST, 80);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("GET "+"......txt "+"HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            + "Host: HOST\r\n"
            + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
            + "\r\n");
writer.flush();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

String serverMsg = reader.readLine();
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("answer: " + serverMsg);
```

Comment: we cannot print the contents of the file which is in the website

Comment: @gray_malkin You'll have to be more specific. Do you have an error? Do you get the wrong output? Does your code simply do nothing? Put yourself in the answerers shoes. Do you want to spend your own time figuring these things out?

Comment: the program only prints 200 OK message but I want to reach the content of the text file.

Comment: What is the last line of the code supposed to be doing? It looks like you are consuming lines of input using `while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` but then you just print out `serverMsg` which has just been set to the first line of the input before the while loop is entered

Comment: @Choc13 This is definitely the answer.

Comment: My aim was to read the contents line by line, but I only get the 200 OK message. The website consists only of a single text file. I want to save that text file in a text file in my computer.

Comment: Thank you, we got the error. We had to write System.out.println("Cevap: " + line);

Comment: simplify and use URL.getConnection() to get the stream for reading.

Comment: @gray_malkin You should accept my answer then if this was the solution to your problem. I had added it as a full answer below.

Comment: i cannot vote because I dont' have enough reputation @Choc13

Comment: @gray_malkin You should still be male to accept the answer below as you asked the question. This is different from voting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing because your question is very unclear, but try changing:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("answer: " + serverMsg);
```

to

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("answer: " + line);
```

In the code you posted you keep assigning to `line`, but you don't actually print it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is doable using sockets, it is much more convenient to use `URL` (and `URLConnection`) instead:

```
URL url = new URL("http://url.of.your.webpage");
try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

This example only uses `URL#openStream()`. If you need more control over the connection, use `URL#openConnection()` instead:

```
URL url = new URL("http://url.of.your.webpage");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
// configure connection
connection.connect();
try (InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
    // ...
}
```